# How to calculate bezier curve handles positions to reproduce a known curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

The question in the title is too general, but this is the idea.

For instance, if we look at a bezier circle, we can notice that the handle position is 0.55213 aside the control point. What is the calculation that leads to this value?

[image]

Similarly, is it possible to use only 3 points and the good handle positions (with some resolution) to have the equivalent of the quadratic bezier curve of geometry nodes?

I'm looking for some explanation for these two particular examples (and eventually for some links to papers or documentations about more general cases).

Possible application of that: using few known points in a GN context instead of iterating over a resampled curve and determining vertices positions.

PS (in case of): the question is not about how bezier curves are calculated, but how to "retro defining" the handles.

---

I've found something that is close to the result thanks to [wikipedia in the Cubic Bézier Curve section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve):

> Any series of 4 distinct points can be converted to a cubic Bézier
> curve that goes through all 4 points in order. Given the starting and
> ending point of some cubic Bézier curve, and the points along the
> curve corresponding to t = 1/3 and t = 2/3, the control points for the
> original Bézier curve can be recovered.[8]

And [the [8] reference leads to this](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225210855/http://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/html/bezier_interpolation.html).

That works pretty well when comparing the result with the quadratic bezier curve of geometry nodes.
Here we can see the calculated handle positions (and the gn node in orange). The two curves offer a nearly perfect superposition.

[image]

But when applied to a circle, this is strange:

[image]

The result is good but there is a significant gap between the curves (as seen above on the right).
Also the handles are not aligned to the control point as their position in (X, Y) are (1.0147, 0.5343).

Here is the way it goes translated in Python from the description given in the link above.

```
# cubic bezier parametric equation
def cubic(t, P0, P1, P2, P3):
    return P0*(1-t)**3 + 3*P1*(1-t)**2*t + 3*P2*(1-t)*t**2 + P3*t**3

# derivative cubic bezier parametric equation
def cubic_prime(t, P0, P1, P2, P3):
    return 3*(P1-P0)*(1-t)**2 + 6*(P2-P1)*(1-t)*t + 3*(P3-P2)*t**2

# quadratic parametric equation
def quadratic(t, P0, P1, P2):
    return P0*(1 - t)**2 + 2*P1*(1-t)*t + P2*t**2

# first handle from known four points
def first_handle(p0, p1, p2, p3):
    return (-5*p0 + 18*p1 - 9*p2 + 2*p3) / 6

# second handle from known four points
def second_handle(p0, p1, p2, p3):
    return (2*p0 - 9*p1 + 18*p2 - 5*p3) / 6
```

The last two functions are the key point. They allow to determinate the first and second handle position from 4 known points on the curve:

- The one at position 0 first control point
- The one at 1/3 along the curve
- The one at 2/3 along the curve
- And finally at position 1 second control point

And finally, two test functions

one for quadratic

```
def quadratic_test():
    # as defined in gn "quadratic bezier"
    QP0 = Vector((-1, 0, 0))
    QP1 = Vector((1, 2, 0))
    QP2 = Vector((1, 0, 0))

    # points on the curve
    q0 = QP0
    q1 = quadratic(1/3, QP0, QP1, QP2)
    q2 = quadratic(2/3, QP0, QP1, QP2)
    q3 = QP2

    # cubic handles
    CP0 = q0
    CP1 = first_handle(q0, q1, q2, q3)
    CP2 = second_handle(q0, q1, q2, q3)
    CP3 = q3

    print(q1, q2)
    print(CP0, CP1, CP2, CP3)
```

and one for circle

```
def circle_test():
    # points on the curve
    s0 = Vector((1, 0, 0))
    s1 = Vector((cos(pi/6), sin(pi/6), 0))
    s2 = Vector((cos(pi/3), sin(pi/3), 0))
    s3 = Vector((0, 1, 0))

    # cubic handles
    CP0 = s0
    CP1 = first_handle(s0, s1, s2, s3)
    CP2 = second_handle(s0, s1, s2, s3)
    CP3 = s3

    print(CP0, CP1, CP2, CP3)
```

(I don't know if there is a mistake somewhere for the circle part)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want, you don't want to know how Bézier curves are calculated - but you want to know how to define the handles? I'm quite sure they have to be calculated based on how the curve itself is calculated. And if you don't need exact mathematical accuracy, I'm sure there are a lot of different handle positions which can make a curve look "close enough" to what it should be. The _Quadratic Bézier_ curve for example is just the graph for $y=x^2$ with $x\in [-1, 1]$, but how you have to define the handles will most likely depend on how a Bézier curve is calculated.

Comment: Interesting one. From exploration alone, so far gleaned that Blender's  cubic-spline approximation to a circle appears **not** to be any of [these](https://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/) . It's the same as a Bézier quadrilateral with 'Automatic' handles. I _think_ [this](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/87a0770bb969ce37d9a41a04c1658ea09c63933a/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/curve.cc#L3561) is the 'Automatic' algorithm for non-f-curves.. I'm not certain enough / have not studied enough to commit to an answer.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann. I'd say "yes and no". Given control points and handles, the curve is calculated. But basically, if you want to have a circle, how to calculate the handles?

Comment: @RobinBetts, thanks for the links... there is something around that I need to learn...

Comment: @lemon I have to admit, since I don't know how the handles are calculated I don't know in which way the function for a circle is needed to achieve that - and hence, in a way, the function for the Bézier curve. And I admit I was thinking ahead on more arbitrary curves which are not as easily described by simple functions like a circle.